# Does php have an equivalent of javascript arrow functions (=>)?

Tags: javascript, php

I know the `=>` symbol is used when constructing arrays in php. But in javascript, you can use the symbol to shorten a function like this:

```
var materials = [
  'Hydrogen',
  'Helium',
  'Lithium',
  'Beryllium'
];

console.log(materials.map(material => material.length));
// expected output: Array [8, 6, 7, 9]
```

where `material` would be the input of the function and `material.length` the return value.

Is there's an equivalent in php?

Comment: What aspects of arrow functions are you interested in, exactly? If you just mean an anonymous function, see e.g. https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php.

Comment: Downvotes for what? Arrow functions is a new feature of php and not everyone knows about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **php7.4** arrow functions are **implemented** according to this rfc https://wiki.php.net/rfc/arrow_functions_v2

Sample here: https://3v4l.org/ddooc, watch the results depending on php version.

```
$array = ['string1', 'longstring'];
print_r(array_map(fn($x) => strlen($x), $array));
```

In older versions of php you still have to use:

```
array_map( 
    function ($x) {
        return strlen($x);
    },
    $array
);
```